# Complexity-free Kolmogorov(-Smirnov)

Tags: code-golf, array

In statistics, sometimes it's useful to know whether two data samples come from the same underlying distribution. One way to do this is to use the two-sample [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test).

Your task will be to write a program that reads in two unsorted nonnegative integer arrays and calculates the main statistic used in the test.

---

Given an array `A` and a real number `x`, define the distribution function `F` by

```
F(A,x) = (#number of elements in A less than or equal to x)/(#number of elements in A)
```

Given two arrays `A1` and `A2`, define

```
D(x) = |F(A1, x) - F(A2, x)|
```

The two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic is the maximum value of `D` over all real `x`.

### Example

```
A1 = [1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 6]
A2 = [3, 4, 5, 4]
```

Then:

```
D(1) = |2/6 - 0| = 1/3
D(2) = |3/6 - 0| = 1/2
D(3) = |4/6 - 1/4| = 5/12
D(4) = |5/6 - 3/4| = 1/12
D(5) = |5/6 - 4/4| = 1/6
D(6) = |6/6 - 4/4| = 0
```

The KS-statistic for the two arrays is `1/2`, the maximum value of `D`.

### Test cases

```
[0] [0] -> 0.0
[0] [1] -> 1.0
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] [2, 3, 4, 5, 6] -> 0.2
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3] [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> 0.4
[1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 6] [3, 4, 5, 4] -> 0.5
[8, 9, 9, 5, 5, 0, 3] [4, 9, 0, 5, 5, 0, 4, 6, 9, 10, 4, 0, 9] -> 0.175824
[2, 10, 10, 10, 1, 6, 7, 2, 10, 4, 7] [7, 7, 9, 9, 6, 6, 5, 2, 7, 2, 8] -> 0.363636
```

### Rules

- You may write a function or a full program. Input may be via STDIN or function argument, and output may be via STDOUT or return value.
- You may assume any unambiguous list or string format for the input, as long as it is consistent for both arrays
- On the off-chance that your language has a builtin for this, you may not use it.
- Answers need to be correct to at least 3 significant figures
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the program in the fewest bytes wins

Comment: Are all inputs going to be integer arrays, or can they contain floating points?

Comment: @KennyTM Just nonnegative integers. I thought I'd keep things simple.

Comment: Is there a maximum value we can assume for arrays? (E.g. all entries of `A` are below `length(A)`?)

Comment: @flawr No you can't assume a maximum value

Comment: I like the title. I'm stile targeting the kolmogorov complexity bagde, but not this time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### APL (<s>29</s> 24)

(Thanks to Zgarb for the extra inspiration.)

```
{⌈/|-⌿⍺⍵∘.(+/≤÷(⍴⊣))∊⍺⍵}
```

This is a function that takes the arrays as its left and right arguments.

```
      8 9 9 5 5 0 3 {⌈/|-⌿⍺⍵∘.(+/≤÷(⍴⊣))∊⍺⍵} 4 9 0 5 5 0 4 6 9 10 4 0 9 
0.1758241758
```

Explanation:

```
{⌈/                                maximum of
   |                               the absolute value of
    -⌿                             the difference between
      ⍺⍵∘.(         )∊⍺⍵          for both arrays, and each element in both arrays
            +/≤                    the amount of items in that array ≤ the element
               ÷                   divided by
                (⍴⊣)              the length of that array
                          }
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do `⍺⍵`! That's handy.

Comment: Also, I think `⍳⌈/` is unnecessary, since the maximum is obtained exactly at one of the array values.

Comment: @Zgarb: you're right of course, I just have to test for each possible array value. That means I can get rid of the `0,` too, as it'll test for that if the array contains it. Thanks! (And that'll teach me, as usually if you have to add in a special case, that means the algorithm isn't simple enough.)

Comment: This is true sorcery, right here.

Comment: @Sp3000: did you write the one-element arrays correctly? You can't just write `1`, as that would be a scalar. You should write `(,1)` instead. If you do that, it works.

Comment: So it does - thanks for clarifying :)

Answer (score 4):

## J - 39

I'm sure can be shorten much more

```
f=:+/@|:@(>:/)%(]#)
>./@:|@((,f])-(,f[))
```

Usage

```
2 10 10 10 1 6 7 2 10 4 7 >./@:|@((,f])-(,f[)) 7 7 9 9 6 6 5 2 7 2 8
0.363636
```

Comment: Does this create a function or use stdin/stdout? What does the second part exactly do? (Looks a bit long for a function call?)

Comment: @flawr A function, similar to APL

Comment: I think you could avoid explicitly defining `f` if you use something like `>./@:|@({.-{:)f"1@,` but I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6) 99 <s>119 128</s>

More or less straightforward JavaScript implementation<s>, probably more golfable</s>.
In the F function I use > instead of <=, as abs(F(a)-F(b)) === abs((1-F(a))-(1-F(b)))

No more function definition as default parameer in this last edit.

As I said, it's straightforward. The F function is the F function, the D function is the unnamed function used in line 2. It's evaluated using .map for each value present in the two arrays, as the max value for `all` reals must be one of these. At last, the spread operator (...) is used to pass the D values array as a parameter list to the max function.

```javascript
K=(a,b)=>Math.max(...a.concat(b).map(x=>
  Math.abs((F=a=>a.filter(v=>v>x).length/a.length)(a)-F(b))
))
```

**Test** In FireFox/FireBug console

```javascript
;[[[0],[0]], [[0],[1]],
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]],
[[3, 3, 3, 3, 3],[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]],
[[1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 6],[3, 4, 5, 4]],
[[8, 9, 9, 5, 5, 0, 3],[4, 9, 0, 5, 5, 0, 4, 6, 9, 10, 4, 0, 9]],
[[2, 10, 10, 10, 1, 6, 7, 2, 10, 4, 7],[7, 7, 9, 9, 6, 6, 5, 2, 7, 2, 8]]]
.forEach(x=>console.log(x[0],x[1],K(x[0],x[1]).toFixed(6)))
```

*Output*

```
[0] [0] 0.000000
[0] [1] 1.000000
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] [2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 0.200000
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3] [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] 0.400000
[1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 6] [3, 4, 5, 4] 0.500000
[8, 9, 9, 5, 5, 0, 3] [4, 9, 0, 5, 5, 0, 4, 6, 9, 10, 4, 0, 9] 0.175824
[2, 10, 10, 10, 1, 6, 7, 2, 10, 4, 7] [7, 7, 9, 9, 6, 6, 5, 2, 7, 2, 8] 0.363636
```

Comment: I am curous about your function `K`: Is it correct that you define other functions `F,D` in the argument list? Does this behave like some optional arguments or so?

Comment: @flawr yes, they are optional arguments with a default value. So avoiding the pollution of global variable space (that's not a problem in code golf, but anyway...)

Comment: Plus, since the function already required 2 variables (thus the brackets), it would be 2 extra bytes to move those variables out of the option var list to inside of the function body.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <s>132</s> <s>108</s> <s>95</s> 88

```py
f=lambda a,x:sum(n>x for n in a)/len(a)
g=lambda a,b:max(abs(f(a,x)-f(b,x))for x in a+b)
```

The input are 2 lists to the function `g`

Thanks to: Sp3000, xnor, undergroundmonorail

*Line 2, first call to `f` reads like "fax". I found that mildly amusing*

Comment: To count the number of elements of a list that satisfy a property, it's shorter to do `sum(n>x for n in a)`. Also, it looks like you're not using `s=filter`. And for `max`, you don't actually need the list brackets; Python lets the function parens double as comprehension parens.

Comment: Thanks! I used `filter` in a previous version, forgot to remove it. Sadly I can't remove the first pair of square brackets since then it will be a generator, which has no `len`.

Comment: you don't need `len`, read the comment again :P

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, <s>33</s> 31 bytes

```
q~_:+f{\f{f<_:+\,d/}}z{~-z}%$W=
```

Input is a CJam styles array of the two arrays.

Example:

```
[[8 9 9 5 5 0 3] [4 9 0 5 5 0 4 6 9 10 4 0 9]]
```

Output:

```
0.17582417582417587
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Answer (score 2):

### Matlab <strike>(121)</strike>(119)

This is a program that takes two lists throu stdin and prints the result to stdout. It is a strightfwd approcht and I tried to golf it as much as possible. `K(a)` returns a *function* that calculates `x -> F(a,x)`. Then the anonymous function `@(x)abs(g(x)-h(x))` which corresponds to the function `D` is applied to every possible integer of `0:max([a,b])` and the maximum of the results is displayed. (`arrayfun` does the same as `map` in other languages: it applies a function to every element of a array)

```
a=input('');b=input('');
K=@(a)@(x)sum(a<=x)/numel(a);
g=K(a);h=K(b);
disp(max(arrayfun(@(x)abs(g(x)-h(x)),0:max([a,b]))))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Erlang, 96 Bytes

[edc65's JavaScript solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/45258/21777) ported to Erlang.

```
f(A,B)->F=fun(A,X)->length([V||V<-A,V>X])/length(A)end,lists:max([abs(F(A,X)-F(B,X))||X<-A++B]).
```

Test:

```
lists:foreach(fun ([H,T] = L) -> io:format("~p ~p~n", [L, w:f(H, T)]) end, [[[0],[0]], [[0],[1]],
        [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]],
        [[3, 3, 3, 3, 3],[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]],
        [[1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 6],[3, 4, 5, 4]],
        [[8, 9, 9, 5, 5, 0, 3],[4, 9, 0, 5, 5, 0, 4, 6, 9, 10, 4, 0, 9]],
        [[2, 10, 10, 10, 1, 6, 7, 2, 10, 4, 7],[7, 7, 9, 9, 6, 6, 5, 2, 7, 2, 8]]]).
```

Output:

```
[[0],[0]] 0.0
[[0],[1]] 1.0
[[1,2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5,6]] 0.20000000000000007
[[3,3,3,3,3],[5,4,3,2,1]] 0.4
[[1,2,1,4,3,6],[3,4,5,4]] 0.5
[[8,9,9,5,5,0,3],[4,9,0,5,5,0,4,6,9,10,4,0,9]] 0.17582417582417587
[[2,10,10,10,1,6,7,2,10,4,7],[7,7,9,9,6,6,5,2,7,2,8]] 0.36363636363636365
```

Answer (score 2):

### STATA 215

This is 90% getting the input into a format that can be used because STATA already has a ksmirnov command.

```
di _r(a)
di _r(b)
file open q using "b.c",w
forv x=1/wordcount($a){
file w q "1,"(word($a,`x'))_n
}
forv x=1/wordcount($b){
file w q "2,"(word($b,`x'))_n
}
file close q
insheet using "b.c"
ksmirnov v2,by(v1)
di r(D)
```

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't think that languages would have a builtin for this...  I just did some research and I decided it would be best to disallow builtins from now on, but you can keep this because it was posted before the rule change :)

Answer (score 2):

### R, 65 bytes

```
f=function(a,b){d=c(a,b);e=ecdf(a);g=ecdf(b);max(abs(e(d)-g(d)))}
```

This function takes two vectors as arguments and returns the maximum difference of their empirical cumulative distribution functions.

If built-ins were allowed, it would reduce to mere 12 bytes:

```
ks.test(a,b)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, <s>76 73</s> 63

Mathematica has the built-in function `KolmogorovSmirnovTest`, but I won't use it here.

```
k=N@MaxValue[Abs[#-#2]&@@(Tr@UnitStep[x-#]/Length@#&/@{##}),x]&
```

Usage:

```
k[{1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 6}, {3, 4, 5, 4}]
```

> 0.5

Answer (score 0):

Quick implementation in Python 3.4.2 (79 bytes):

```py
F=lambda A,x:len([n for n in A if n<=x])/len(A)
D=lambda x:abs(F(A1,x)-F(A2,x))
```

Example:

```
>>> A1 = [-5, 10, 8, -2, 9, 2, -3, -4, -4, 9]
>>> A2 = [-5, -3, -10, 8, -4, 1, -7, 6, 9, 5, -7]
>>> D(0)
0.045454545454545414
```

Comment: The requirement is to find the maximum value of D(x) for all integers values of x. Please comply to the problem spec.

Comment: Welcome! As Optimizer says, the task is to find the maximum value of `D`, not to just implement `D` as a function. Also, I'm sorry if I wasn't clear, but you can't assume that `A1` and `A2` are already defined variables (you can put them in the lambda though, e.g. `lambda x,A1,A2:` - that's okay)

Comment: Also I've added some syntax highlighting - I think it makes it look prettier :)

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm new here.

Comment: No problems :) If anything's unclear, you can ask in the comments. But once again, welcome!

Answer (score 0):

### Java - <strike>633</strike> 622 Bytes

Ok,first up, trying to get better at java so thats why i tried it in java, I know i'll never do well, but eh, its fun.
second, I honestly thought i could do this in way less, then i got to the stage where there were doubles everywhere, and the method declarations meant using methods only saved 4-5 chars in total. 
in short, i'm a bad golfer.

edit: usage format> java K "2,10,10,10,1,6,7,2,10,4,7" "7,7,9,9,6,6,5,2,7,2,8"

```
import java.lang.*;
class K{public static void main(String[]a){double[]s1=m(a[0]);double[]s2=m(a[1]);
int h=0;if(H(s1)<H(s2))h=(int)H(s2);else h=(int)H(s1);double[]D=new double[h];
for(int i=0;i<h;i++){D[i]=Math.abs(F(s1,i)-F(s2,i));}System.out.println(H(D));}
static double[]m(String S){String[]b=S.split(",");double[]i=new double[b.length];
for(int j=0;j<b.length;j++){i[j]=new Integer(b[j]);}return i;}
static double H(double[]i){double t=0;for(int j=0;j<i.length;j++)
{if(i[j]>t)t=i[j];}return t;}
static double F(double[]A,int x){double t=0;double l=A.length;
for(int i=0;i<l;i++){if(A[i]<=x)t++;}return t/l;}}
```

Comment: you were right. updating.

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell <s>96</s> 83

```
l=fromIntegral.length
a%x=l(filter(<=x)a)/l a
a!b=maximum$map(\x->abs$a%x-b%x)$a++b
```

(!) is the kolmogorov-smirnov function which takes two lists

Comment: some quick golfs: use `map` rather than `fmap`; use `maximum` rather than `foldr1 max`; define `l=fromIntegral.length` and you can get rid of `i`, and then you can shorten `%` to `l(filter(<=x)a)/l a`. Gets it down to 84!

Answer (score 0):

## R, 107 bytes

Different Approach

```
f=function(a,b){e=0
d=sort(unique(c(a,b)))
for(i in d-min(diff(d))*0.8)e=max(abs(mean(a<i)-mean(b<i)),e)
e}
```

Ungolfed

```
f=function(a,b){
    e=0
    d=sort(unique(c(a,b)))
    d=d-min(diff(d))*0.8
    for(i in d) {
        f=mean(a<i)-mean(b<i)
        e=max(e,abs(f))
    }
    e
}
```